# OpenLayers WFS protocol query after vector layer creation

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I want to be able to create a layer on init, then load features from a [WFS protocol](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS-js.html) afterward. I'm having trouble doing this.

Using WFS protocol in vector constructor **works fine and is not my problem**:
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/wfs-filter.js

What i want to do is Add a layer like such:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Results", {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});
```

Then Query it using the [WFS Protocol](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS-js.html).... this is what i can't get to work... what i have so far is:

```
var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    version: "1.1.0",
    url: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.EndPointURL,
    featurePrefix: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featurePrefix,
    featureType: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featureType,
    featureNS: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featureNS,
    geometryName: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.geometryName
});


var response = protocol.read({
    maxFeatures: Search.Properties.maxResults,
    callback: function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        layer.addFeatures(resp.features);
    }
});
```

resp.features gets populated fine. My main problem is I can't find where to specify my filter and  projection as i can in the Vector constructor. Even though i specified the projection in the vector constructor, when i addFeatures from my WFS response, they come back in a different projection because they end up really small spooning the west coast of Africa. Same thing with the filter. I don't see that WFS protocol alone supports applying a filter? It only seems to work in conjunction with a vector layer constructor.

This seems wrong though because the [WFS protocol](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol/WFS-js.html) as described by the OGC support the filter and when openlayers submits it's WFS request via the vector constructor, it does indeed include it just fine. There should be a way to specify projection and filter in the WFS protocol alone?

**EDIT #1:**

What i have now:

```
var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    version: "1.1.0",
    url: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.EndPointURL,
    featurePrefix: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featurePrefix,
    featureType: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featureType,
    featureNS: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featureNS,
    geometryName: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.geometryName,
    srsName: "EPSG:4326"
//    ,
//    defaultFilter: myFilter
});

protocol.mergeWithDefaultFilter(Search.GetWFSSpatialFilters());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to set a [defaultFilter](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol-js.html#OpenLayers.Protocol.defaultFilter), or once the protocol is created you can use [mergeWithDefaultFilter](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol-js.html#OpenLayers.Protocol.mergeWithDefaultFilter).

```
var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    version: "1.1.0",
    url: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.EndPointURL,
    featurePrefix: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featurePrefix,
    featureType: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featureType,
    featureNS: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.featureNS,
    geometryName: MapBase.Configuration.GeoServer.WFS_Service.geometryName,
    srsName: "EPSG:4326",
    defaultFilter: myFilter
});

protocol.mergeWithDefaultFilter(myNewFilter);
```

For the projection you can add in the following for WFS 1.1.0:

```
srsName: "EPSG:4326"
```

A few more details [here](http://geographika.co.uk/mapserver-openlayers-and-the-wfs-maze).

Comment: I've added an Edit to my question. Though the results still end up off the coast of Africa. I've found a format property that takes an internal and external projection but still am trying to get it to work.

Comment: Sorry this worked : srsName: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")

Comment: You should be able to see the requests in FireBug. Check the srsName is being set, and then look at the coordinates to see they come back in this projection.